# How to put my tomcat servlet / jsp pages under the www folder?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I don't have much experience in server side webdev and I want to ask a specific question.

My goal is to have my static html code coexist with my dynamic jsp/servlet pages without having the 8080 port. I want them both to be at 80 port.

For Instance I want to be able to type the following urls:

```
mywebsite.com/index.html <-- static home page

mywebsite.com/folder/page.html <-- static page

mywebsite.com/myApp/index.jsp <-- dynamic jsp page (without the 8080)

mywebsite.com/myApp/folder/ <-- dynamic servlet page (without the 8080)
```

I don't want to have the following urls:

```
mywebsite.com:8080/myApp/index.jsp

mywebsite.com:8080/myApp/folder/
```

How do I manage to do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Reverse proxy (Nginx/Apache) to manage access to dynamic back service and serve static files efficiently.

Comment: Thanks you. I solved my problem thanks to that.
I used the guide on this page (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/howto/reverse_proxy.html) to do a correct configuration.